# How to fetch value from a CLASS(ShowVideo) to use in second CLASS(ImageViewer) (according to my program) by using PyQt5 QThread

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

I am trying to retrieve the value of `x` i.e is a counter from class `ShowVideo` and to display the counter in a button in `ImageViewer` class. Video is running perfectly, but I m not getting the logic on how to show counter when video starts running. All the function should work simultaneously, here `i` as a variable is the counter name declared in inside function `startVideo()` that comes under `showVideo` class. I want to update the value on button i.e `button_in(class ImageViewer, method InitUI())` as a counter.

'''

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal,QRect,QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

filenameOpen =0

class ShowVideo(QtCore.QObject):# its only running a videooo

    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(filenameOpen)

    VideoSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QImage)


#############################################
    # newValue=QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    # stopped= pyqtSignal()
#################################################    
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        # super(ShowVideo, self).__init__(parent)
        super().__init__()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def startVideo(self):

        run_video = True
        #     self.counterThread.startVideo()QImage
        x=0
        while run_video:
            # ret, image = self.camera.read()
            ret, image = self.camera.read()
            height, width, channels = image.shape
            frame=image.copy()
            frameClone = frame.copy()       
            # frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1920, 1080))

            color_swapped_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            height, width, _ = color_swapped_image.shape


            qt_image = QtGui.QImage(color_swapped_image.data,
                                    width, 
                                    height,
                                    color_swapped_image.strides[0],
                                    QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)                    
            self.VideoSignal.emit(qt_image) 
            # return x
            # print(x)
            # x=x+1

class ImageViewer(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        left=0
        top=0
        width=1920
        height=1080
        iconName="icon.png"
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(iconName))
        self.setGeometry(left,top,width,height)
        self.image = QtGui.QImage()
        self.initUI()
        self.show()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Emotion Analysis')
        button_video = QPushButton(self)
        button_file = QPushButton(self)
        button_play = QPushButton(self)
        self.button_in=QPushButton(self)
        button_out=QPushButton(self)
        button_total=QPushButton(self)
        self.button_stop = QPushButton(self)
        self.label_image=QLabel(self)
        label_image_blank=QLabel(self)
        label_in=QLabel(self)
        label_out=QLabel(self)
        label_total=QLabel(self)    

        # button definations>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        button_video.setGeometry((QRect(10,30,90,65)))# syntax(x,y,<>,^)
        button_video.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("securitycamera.png"))
        button_video.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50,50))
        # button.setToolTip("This is Click Me Button")
        button_video.setToolTip("<h4>Live Stream<h4>")
        button_video.clicked.connect(vid.startVideo)

        button_file.setGeometry((QRect(110,30,90,65)))# syntax(x,y,<>,^)
        button_file.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("file.png"))
        button_file.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50,50))
        button_file.setToolTip("<h4>Add new connection<h4>")
        button_file.clicked.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit) # this line is also working condition, the quit() method is defined above 

        button_play.setGeometry((QRect(1710,30,90,65)))# syntax(x,y,<>,^)
        # button_play.setGeometry((QRect(1710,300,90,65)))# syntax(x,y,<>,^)
        button_play.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("play_red.png"))
        button_play.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50,50))
        button_play.setToolTip("<h4>Play video<h4>")
        button_play.clicked.connect(vid.startVideo)

        self.button_stop.setGeometry((QRect(1820,30,90,65)))# syntax(x,y,<>,^)
        self.button_stop.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("stop.png"))
        self.button_stop.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50,50))
        self.button_stop.setToolTip("<h4>Stop Video<h4>")
        self.button_stop.clicked.connect(QApplication.instance().quit)
#############################################################
        self.button_in.setGeometry((QRect(1710,500,90,45)))# syntax(x,y,<>,^)
        self.button_in.setText("0")# it should be updated while counter runs
        # self.button_in.setText(x)
        self.button_in.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif",20))

        # self.counterThread=QThread()
        # self.counter=ShowVideo()
        # self.counter.moveToThread(self.counterThread)
        # self.button_in.clicked.connect(self.startCounting)
        # self.vid.newValue.connect(self.button_in.setText)
        # self.counterThread.started.connect(self.counter.startVideo)





#####################################################################
        button_out.setGeometry((QRect(1710,550,90,45)))# syntax(x,y,<>,^)
        button_out.setText("0")
        button_out.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif",20))

        button_total.setGeometry((QRect(1710,600,90,45)))# syntax(x,y,<>,^)
        button_total.setText("0")
        button_total.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif",20))


        # label definations>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

        self.label_image.setGeometry((QRect(10,110,1500,900))) # syntax(x,y,<>,^)
        self.label_image.setPixmap(QPixmap("black.jpg"))
        self.label_image.setScaledContents(True)

        label_in.setGeometry((QRect(1600,500,100,50))) # syntax(x,y,<>,^)
        label_in.setText("In")
        label_in.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif",20))

        label_out.setGeometry((QRect(1600,550,100,50))) # syntax(x,y,<>,^)
        label_out.setText("Out")
        label_out.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif",20))

        label_total.setGeometry((QRect(1600,600,100,50))) # syntax(x,y,<>,^)
        label_total.setText("Total")
        label_total.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Sanserif",20))     

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QImage)
    def setImage(self, image):
        self.label_image.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
        # self.vid.newValue.connect(self.button_in.setText)



    # @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    # def startCounting(self,x):
    # #     # if not self.counterThread.isRunning():
    # #     #     self.counterThread.startVideo()
    # #     # pass
    #     self.vid.newValue.connect(self.button_in.setText)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    thread = QtCore.QThread() #thread declareation
    thread.start()
    vid = ShowVideo() # calling 1st class
    vid.moveToThread(thread)
    image_viewer = ImageViewer() #calling second class 
    vid.VideoSignal.connect(image_viewer.setImage)  
    # vid.VideoSignal.connect(image_viewer.startCounting)   
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) '''
```

Comment: Do not edit your question with noise just to attract attention.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest is to emit the frame number with the image when emitting `ShowVideo.VideoSignal` in `ShowVideo.startVedio` and connecting `vid.VideoSignal` to `image_viewer.setText`, i.e.

```
class ShowVideo(QtCore.QObject):

    VideoSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QImage, int)

    ....

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def startVideo(self):

        ....

        x += 1
        self.VideoSignal.emit(qt_image, x)

....

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ....

    vid.VideoSignal.connect(lambda img, frame: image_viewer.button_in.setText(str(frame)) )
```

Comment: It's working well with the counter, but however, the camera is getting switched on but **not able to run video**